# How do I implement "use 5.010" in an exporter module?

Tags: perl

I want to be able to say:

```
use this;
```

and have it be equivalent to:

```
use 5.010;
```

So how would I write the `import` function for the module `this`?

```
package this;

sub import {
   my $caller = caller;
   ???
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is import feature pragma:

```
package myfeature;
require feature;

sub import {
    feature->import(':5.10');
}

1;
```

See feature pragma documentation for more: http://perldoc.perl.org/feature.html

Comment: @user5402: I’m not convinced that this is a good idea. I don’t appreciate regular modules that reach up into my scope and diddle my pragmas. Why can’t you just have the caller do this for themselves? Which one of the `say`, `state`, or `switch` features is it that you’re trying to get turned on?

Comment: @tchirst - read my response to @ysth's answer. My `this` module is not a regular module - it's more of an application-specific configuration module.

Answer (score 1):

You could just use the Modern::Perl Module, which automatically enables 5.10.x

Answer (score 0):

I can see why you want to do this, but it is nevertheless not a good idea.  Currently, the `use VERSION` verifies that you are running at least that version of perl and enables features introduced in the specified version.  In the future it will also actually modify the operation of some features to match how they worked in that version.  You really want it to be specified for each file, not for your whole codebase, or you will be asking for trouble when you want to change it.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm going to run into a problem with the way I'm using the `this` module. Can you give an example of the situation you're talking about?

Comment: suppose in 5.18, the match operation in scalar context is changed to return a match object on success, but only for code that declares `use 5.018` or above.  If each of your sources has a use VERSION declaration that indicates the version of perl it was written for, they remain unaffected, even when you decide you want new code to use 5.18 features.

Comment: I see your point, but in this case my `this` module is not intended to be a general purpose module (like `List::Util`). Rather, it is a configuration module, and it's purpose is to set up a particular environment for its user. It's a configuration that is shared by several other modules, and that's why I want to factor it out. That said, I was unaware that the behavior/expectations of `use VERSION` could change in the future, and so I might look to implement it in a more future-proof way. In any case, since the policy is factored out, it should be easy to change if and when I need to.123

Comment: umm.  my whole point is that minimum version or features used isn't a configuration kinda thing.  it's an attribute of the source code and when it was written and in the future may be hard to determine just from imspection of the code